# Laravel - Larabook "Method [execute] does not exist."

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm following the Laracasts's Larabook tutorial. I'm on the 'Following Users' part. I added a follow button to all user's profiles, but I'm stuck with "BadMethodCallException Method [execute] does not exist." error. Here is my FollowsController;

```
<?php

use Larabook\Users\FollowUserCommand;

class FollowsController extends \BaseController {

/**
 * Follow a user
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    //id of the user to follow
    //id of the authenticated user
    $input = array_add(Input::all(), 'userId', Auth::id());
    $this->execute(FollowUserCommand::class, $input);
    Flash::success('You are now following this user.');
    return Redirect::back();
}


/**
 * Unfollow a user
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}

Comment: I'm not familiar with the tutorial but you call `$this->execute()` and your controller doesn't have an `execute` function. That's the problem.

Comment: The error message (rather clearly) tells you that you don't have a method called execute. It shouldn't be too hard to figure out how to fix that problem. :)

Comment: @lukasgeiter I do have the execute method. It comes with laracasts commander package. That's why I can't figure out the problem everything looks just normal.

Comment: Do you have `use CommanderTrait;` somewhere? Either in the `BaseController` or in this controller

Comment: Nope. I did not use a Trait. @lukasgeiter

Comment: In laravel 5.1 you have to use `dispatch` call instead of `execute`. Watch https://laracasts.com/lessons/laravel-5-commands for more info 

So it has to be `$this->dispatch(FollowUserCommand::class, $input);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [instructions of the **laracasts/Commander** package](https://github.com/laracasts/Commander#the-controller) you need to inject the `Commander Trait` in your controller to be able to access methods like `execute`.

You can do this either in your `BaseController` so you can use it in every controller that extends `BaseController`:

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    use CommanderTrait;
}
```

Or just in the controller itself:

```
class FollowsController extends \BaseController {
    use CommanderTrait;

    // your methods
}
```

Comment: That was the answer. Thanks so much you just saved my night.